# How group of order $21$ arises naturally?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, finite-groups

I was explaining following theorem in undergraduates:

> "If $|G|=pq$ with $p>q$ and $q\nmid p-1$ then $G$ must be cyclic".

"But what about $|G|=21=7.3$? Here $3\mid (7-1)$". Students stuck to say something about $G$. Then I tried to explain that that *there is* a non-cyclic (hence non-abelian) group of order $21$. I tried to write the collection of maps $x\mapsto ax+b$ where $b$ is in field of order $7$ and $a$ is a cube root of unity in the field of order $7$. I soon realized that I moved partially out of Group Theory.

How can we *illustrate* easily the example of non-abelian group of order $21$ to undergraduates with minimum prerequisite from Group Theory?

Comment: You may want to check out the third example on the Wikipedia page for Frobenius groups: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_group

Comment: In this example, the natural choice of elements $\sigma$ of order $3$ are rotation around center of Fano plane. Then how can we naturally choose element of order $7$ to create group of order $21$? Does every choice suffices?

Comment: You rarely find "natural" examples of interesting groups entirely inside group theory. But you can view the group you described as a semidirect product of $\mathbb Z/7$ with $\mathbb Z/3$. There is a simple map from $\mathbb Z/3$ to the automorphism group of $\mathbb Z/7$.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to give examples like this without any machinery at all. Your attempt is quite ok, but probably inaccessible to many students. I would consider playing with the relations like in Alan's answer, but then you run into the problem that from the relations alone you cannot reliably see whether all the 21 elements are necessarily distinct, so you also need a concrete model. You could represent your linear polynomials as 2x2 matrices with entries from $\Bbb{Z}_7$. Or you can view the group as a subgroup of $S_7$ with generators $b=(1234567)$ and $a=(235)(476)$.

Comment: @Groups Yeah, I believe any choice should suffice.

Answer (score 3):

Personally,  I'd probably just give them the group in presentation form that you get from the semidirect product construction of it....and for the more advanced students, explain semidirect products.

$\langle a,b\mid a^3=b^7=e,aba^{-1}=b^2\rangle$,  and show them that that well defines a group of order 21 that is non abelian.